# Direction of tap out of water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

Sorry for the weird question, but here goes.

I am planning to install an electrical, tanked water heater.

For the inlet, I will screw a pressure relief valve directly in the cold water pipe, and screw the inlet pipe of the water heater to it:

[image: pressure relief valve]

This type of device will automatically drain the water when the pressure gets too high.

For the outlet, I have been advised to plug a tap like this directly into the hot water pipe, and the outlet pipe of the water heater into it :

[image: out pipe]

I was surprised to be recommended a connection that has a 90 degrees angle, with a valve. Why not a simple straight connection? Does the 90degrees angle matter? If so, why?
Knowing that my water heater will be higher than the connection, should this angled connection face up or down?

In addition, I was thinking of adding a pressure meter just before this outlet connection, so that I can monitor the pressure myself and make sure there's no excess pressure going into my pipes (they are old and I am terrified of the work involved if they burst). Is that reasonable or will that create issues?

Comment: Is this a tankless water heater?....most water heaters tank and tankless have a t&p relief valve included and a designated outlet for it... ask more questions because t&p relief valves are nothing you want to get wrong as they can be very dangerous if installed incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd *strongly* suggest that you ask the "why" questions to whoever it was that made these recommendations to you. That person may well know your local codes and/or the particular unit you're planning on installing better than any of us will. That said...

---

Generally, I believe your "security group" is called a "pressure relief valve" - it opens automatically if pressure gets too high, and drains the water someplace, hopefully where it's designed to go (like a drain). I'm not sure, however, what this has to do with your question at all.

The item in your 2nd image looks like it's got a garden hose thread on it. Beyond that, I can't imagine why it matters whether it's a straight or angled fitting beyond the fact that the angled fitting will more easily allow you to turn the outbound plumbing along the wall, which is where you probably want it. If you need the plumbing to go straight out from the tank, I'm sure you could use a straight fitting here.

Having a valve right at the outlet from the heater allows you to shut off water flow to the entire house if necessary for plumbing repairs, preventing pipe freezing in case of power loss in freezing temperatures, etc.

Generally, the outlet of the valve points in the direction the next section of plumbing needs to go. If you need to run up from your outlet, point the valve up; if down, point it down; likewise for left or right.

I wouldn't see any issue with installing a pressure gauge right off the hot water heater. Make sure that the gauge you pick will support the temperature of water coming out of your heater. I would install a valve *before* the gauge, though, just in case the gauge fails & needs to be replaced. The valve is a handy shut off to keep your floors mostly dry while removing/replacing the gauge.

Again, confirm all this with your local building/plumbing inspector to ensure that it meets all applicable local codes.

Answer (score 0):

I would check with your "code enforcement officer" for his OK on what you are planning to do. That said, the normal device for an over pressure situation is a Temperature and pressure relief valve called a T&P valve and not a pressure relief only device. If this tank was not a heated tank but was a storage tank only, a pressure relief valve would suffice. Make sure that the relieving pressure part of this safety valve does not exceed the pressure rating of the tank it is protecting. Also, it can not be installed on the cold water supply since that will defeat the temperature sensor of the device. New tanks have a dedicated thread for installing the T&P valve. Years ago, before tank manufacturers supplied the dedicated spot we would install a 3/4" brass tee in the tanks outlet and install the T&P valve into the top of the tee and install the hot water supply line into the "bull end" of the tee. Inlet and outlet isolation valves are always recommended and a pressure gauge is also OK. If you just want to occasionally check the water line's pressure, just buy a domestic gauge that comes with a hose bibb connection and screw it on to an outlet that has a hose end thread such as a laundry tub faucet. These can be bought at any good hardware store or at the orange or blue big box store.

my 2 cents